# Uncaught TypeError: Object invitation has no method '_create'

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm getting this error from my controller:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object invitation has no method '_create'
DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.createRecord ember-data.js?body=1:1580
App.GroupController.Ember.ObjectController.extend.actions.createInvitation group_controller.js?body=1:11
Ember.ActionHandler.Ember.Mixin.create.send ember.js?body=1:18346
runRegisteredAction ember.js?body=1:37748
Backburner.run ember.js?body=1:6019
Ember.run ember.js?body=1:6427
handleRegisteredAction ember.js?body=1:37746
handleActionEvent ember.js?body=1:21917
Ember.handleErrors ember.js?body=1:908
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:21909
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:4625
elemData.handle
```

Here's what my controller looks like:

```
App.GroupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  invitation: (->
    @store.createRecord 'invitation',
      group: @get 'model'
  ).property 'model'
  actions:
    createInvitation: ->
      controller = @
      @get('invitation').save().then (invitation) ->
        controller.get('model.invitations').addObject invitation
```

I have no clue how to debug this.

Here is my model and data store.

```
App.Invitation = DS.Model.extend
  owner: DS.belongsTo 'user',
    async: true
  group: DS.belongsTo 'group'

App.Invitation.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1
    group: 1
    user: 1
  }
]

App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
```

I'm using `Ember 1.4.0`.

Comment: Please give me feedback along with your down votes.

Comment: True that, pointless vote, what version of Ember Data are you using?  Some of your methodology is old (I'll update once you give a version)

Comment: @kingpin2k I am using Ember 1.4.0. It's straight from the `ember-rails-gem`. I am following some of the material found in the CodeSchool course. It seems like every other tutorial is using a different version with different APIs.

Comment: Ember and Ember-Data are different products, can you find your version of Ember Data please?